# Insert where in join, code confused

Tags: mysql, sql

This code returns me the most used words in a column in TEXT format called `description` and is on the table 'messages`.

However I can not stick this in the WHERE code:

`messages.tag = 'HELLO'`

I need it to do what it already does, but with this WHERE I tried this code and gave not sure:

```
SELECT message, count(message) as count

FROM (
  SELECT 
      messages.id, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(messages.message, ' ', count.n), ' ', -1)  as message 
  FROM 
  (select (h*100+t*10+u+1) n from
    (select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
    (select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B,
    (select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
    select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C
  )  as count
  INNER JOIN messages
    ON CHAR_LENGTH(messages.message)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(messages.message, ' ',''))>=count.n-1 
   ORDER BY id, n
) x
WHERE LENGTH(message) >= 5
    AND messages.tag = 'HELLO'
GROUP BY message
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: what is question?? be clear

Comment: @Piyush Insert the WHERE in this code for it to catch the most common words in `description` column when `tag` = HELLO

Comment: Or is it only me return the most comunns words in `descriptiption` column when the column TAG = HELLO

Comment: just use WHERE messages.tag = 'HELLO' in inner query above the line ORDER BY id, n

Comment: I think it should be like, not equal to 'HELLO', description field only equals 'HELLO' not true always, it contains

Answer (score 1):

You have to move that `where` clause into the subquery.  The `messages` alias is not known in the outer query:

```
FROM (SELECT messages.id, 
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(messages.message, ' ', count.n), ' ', -1)  as message 
      FROM  (select (h*100+t*10+u+1) n
             from (select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                   select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
                  (select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                   select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B,
                  (select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
                   select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C
           )  count INNER JOIN
           messages
           ON CHAR_LENGTH(messages.message)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(messages.message, ' ','')) >= count.n-1 
      WHERE messages.tag = 'HELLO'
      ORDER BY id, n
) x
```

The other condition stays in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think `messages.tag` should be like, not equal to 'HELLO'

```
SELECT message, count(message) as count
FROM (
       SELECT 
          messages.id, 
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(messages.message, ' ', count.n), ' ', -1)  as message 
       FROM 
        (
          select (h*100+t*10+u+1) n 
          from
          (
            select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
            union
            select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
          (select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
            union
          select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B,
          (select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
          union
           select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C
          ) count
        INNER JOIN messages
        ON CHAR_LENGTH(messages.message)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(messages.message, ' ',''))>=count.n-1
        WHERE messages.tag like '%HELLO%'   
        ORDER BY id, n
      ) x
WHERE LENGTH(message) >= 5        
GROUP BY message
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
```